# How to create a nut roast and stuffing that don't taste and feel too similar

Tags: vegetarian, roast, stuffing

I'm going to be preparing a vegetarian Christmas dinner this year and will be using a nut roast as the main dish, but I'm worried that it will be too much like a giant piece of stuffing.

The nut roast will contain mushrooms, celery, leek, breadcrumbs, chestnuts and cranberries.

I've checked the recipes for both and they all sound very similar - nuts, fruit and breadcrumbs. Is there any way I can make these two distinctive dishes?

Comment: Can you give us a clue as to what you're planning for your nut roast?  It's explain how to improve over what you have without knowing where we're starting from.

Comment: @Joe I've added a list of ingredients I'm planning to use for my roast. Is there anything else you need to know?

Comment: Speaking as a long-time non-meat-eater, I suggest rethinking the menu.  Wiggy meat substitutes always end up tasting like cardboard imitations.  My recommendation is to make good food which is normally vegetarian.  If you like stuffed things, for example what about a vegetable kibbe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chris

I think you're going to struggle to make two distinctive dishes whilst essentially using the same ingredients for both of them - therein lies your problem.

Do you *have* to use cranberries *and* chestnuts in both? There's many different types of vegetarian stuffings you might use that would compliment your nut roast rather than almost copy it.

How about an Apricot and Hazlenut stuffing to go with your nut roast? C'mon use your imagination, run free and wild! Do a search for Apricot and Hazlenut stuffing there's plenty out there. How about a pureed butter bean and truffle sauce to go with it?

Your cooking is only limited by your own imagination.